# java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: org/glassfish/hk2/api/servicelocatorfactory$createpolicy

Tags: java, rest, jersey, glassfish, hk2

Why am I getting error even though I added all the required jars.
I am trying to build rest client using JERSEY

```
client=ClientBuilder.newClient();
response = client.target("https://XXX/rest/api/2/search?jql="+query).request("application/json").header(authorizationHeaderName, authorizationHeaderValue).get();

responseBody = response.readEntity(String.class);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("issues");
```

added jars:
[JARs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9mOy.png)

Comment: can you post full stack trace, are you getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException along with it?

Comment: @SasiKathimanda java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:138)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:109)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:64)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ServiceLocatorFactory$createPolicy is part of the hk2-api 2.4.* and above. You are using a lower version of hk2-api.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.Now I am getting a new error

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/moxy/json/internal/ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider
 at org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonFeature.configure(MoxyJsonFeature.java:92)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:714)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:644)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.configureMetaProviders(ClientConfig.java:372)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.ja

Comment: Use jersey-all and use maven dependency so it resolves all your jar dependencies